# Need to reduce the query optimization time in postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, query-performance, postgresql-10

Use Case: Need to find the index and totalCount of the particular id in the table

I am having a table ann_details which has 60 million records and based on where condition I need to retrieve the rows along with index of that id

Query:

```
with a as (
    select an.id, row_number() over (partition by created_at) as rn
    from annotation an
    where ( an.layer_id = '47afb169-aed2-4378-ab13-897836275da3' or an.job_id = '' or an.task_id = '') and
     an.category_id in (10019)

) select (select count(1) from a ) as totalCount , rn-1 as index from a where a.id= '47afb169-aed2-4378-ab13-897836275da3_a93f0758-8fe0-4c76-992f-0be17e5618bf_484484101';
```

Output:

```
totalCount index
1797124,1791143
```

Execution Time: 5 sec 487 ms

explain and analyze

```
CTE Scan on a  (cost=872778.54..907545.00 rows=7722 width=16) (actual time=5734.572..5735.989 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: ((id)::text = '47afb169-aed2-4378-ab13-897836275da3_a93f0758-8fe0-4c76-992f-0be17e5618bf_484484101'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1797123
  CTE a
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.68..838031.38 rows=1544318 width=97) (actual time=133.660..3831.998 rows=1797124 loops=1)
          ->  Index Only Scan using test_index_test_2 on annotation an  (cost=0.68..814866.61 rows=1544318 width=89) (actual time=133.647..2660.009 rows=1797124 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (category_id = 10019)
                Filter: (((layer_id)::text = '47afb169-aed2-4378-ab13-897836275da3'::text) OR ((job_id)::text = ''::text) OR ((task_id)::text = ''::text))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 3773007
                Heap Fetches: 101650
  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=34747.15..34747.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2397.391..2397.392 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  CTE Scan on a a_1  (cost=0.00..30886.36 rows=1544318 width=0) (actual time=0.017..2156.210 rows=1797124 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.487 ms
Execution time: 5771.080 ms
```

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX test_index_test_2 ON public.annotation USING btree (category_id,created_at,layer_id,job_id,task_id,id);
```

From application we will be passing the job_id or task_id or layer_id and rest 2 will be passed as empty

Need help in optimizing the query to get the response in 2 sec

Query Plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/mXme

Comment: Instead of using with as , used temp table and below is the query for reference :

https://explain.depesz.com/s/wZHe

Comment: `count(1)` is actually slower than `count(*)` but I doubt it makes a difference here.

Comment: What if you use `count(*) over ()` inside the CTE instead of doing it in the outer query? Btw: `row_number()` without an `order by` usually doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name , updated as suggested and still taking the same time 

https://explain.depesz.com/s/wZHe

Comment: The query makes no sense to me. If you explain the objective so I understand it, I can try rewriting it. As a first try, user a subquery in the `FROM` clause instead of a CTE.

Comment: I am having a table of n records in which I need to find index of the particular record along with total Count of the records with the condition

Step 1 : Applying where condition on table - layer_id and category_id
Step 2 : Got the id and corresponding row_number 
Step 3 : Applied the id condition on the sub query ( where we got the id , rown_number ) and got the total count and respective index 

Using Subquery : https://explain.depesz.com/s/wZHe

Comment: "From application we will be passing the job_id or task_id or layer_id and rest 2 will be passed as empty"  First step is to stop doing that.